# How to reshape wide continuous data into long categorical data?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

My data are in the following wide format, in rows according to `SUBJECT_ID`, with a total of observations of variables `X` and `Y` and then various columns of metadata e.g. `SUBJECT_BIRTHYEAR`, `SUBJECT_HOMETOWN`:

```
variableX    variableY    SUBJECT_ID     SUBJECT_BIRTHYEAR     SUBJECT_HOMETOWN
2            1            A              1950                  Townsville
1            2            B              1951                  Villestown
```

I would like to transfom these into the following long format, where for each observation of variable `X` and `Y` for each `SUBJECT_ID`:

```
VARIABLE     SUBJECT_ID     SUBJECT_BIRTHYEAR     SUBJECT_HOMETOWN
X            A              1950                  Townsville
X            A              1950                  Townsville
Y            A              1950                  Townsville
X            B              1951                  Villestown
Y            B              1951                  Villestown
Y            B              1951                  Villestown
```

Specific to my question is how to transform *n* observations of a continuous variable into *n* rows of categorical data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: @duckmayr Yes, they are similar questions, but specific to my question is the query of how to transform *n* observations of a continuous variable into *n* rows of categorical data. I've added an edit to my question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="variableX    variableY    SUBJECT_ID     SUBJECT_BIRTHYEAR     SUBJECT_HOMETOWN
2            1            A              1950                  Townsville
1            2            B              1951                  Villestown", header=TRUE)
```

Solution

```
library(tidyverse)
result <- df %>%
        nest(variableX, variableY, .key="VARIABLE") %>%
        mutate(VARIABLE = map(VARIABLE, function(i) {
                                    vec <- unlist(i)
                                    rep(gsub("variable", "", names(vec)), times=vec)
                                })) %>%
        unnest()

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  # SUBJECT_ID SUBJECT_BIRTHYEAR SUBJECT_HOMETOWN VARIABLE
      # <fctr>             <int>           <fctr>    <chr>
# 1          A              1950       Townsville        X
# 2          A              1950       Townsville        X
# 3          A              1950       Townsville        Y
# 4          B              1951       Villestown        X
# 5          B              1951       Villestown        Y
# 6          B              1951       Villestown        Y
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! One point of clarification: is it possible to implement this as a function (so I can call it on a list of multiple dataframes) or is there a conflict in how `%>%` is handled? I haven't been successful and am not sure why.

Comment: It's likely not an issue with `%>%` but with how column-names are dealt with. You could either look up previous posts on `non-standard evaluation` or post as another question.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for inverting a call to `dcast()` which has reshaped the data from long to wide format using `length()` as aggregation function.

This can be achieved by a call to `melt()` plus some additional transformations:

```
library(data.table)
# reshape wide back to long format
long <- melt(setDT(wide), measure.vars = c("variableX", "variableY"))[
  # undo munging of variable names
  , variable := stringr::str_replace(variable, "^variable", "")][]
# undo effect of aggregation by length()
result <- long[long[, rep(.I, value)]][
  # beautify result
  order(SUBJECT_ID), !"value"]
result
```

> ```
>    SUBJECT_ID SUBJECT_BIRTHYEAR SUBJECT_HOMETOWN variable
> 1:          A              1950       Townsville        X
> 2:          A              1950       Townsville        X
> 3:          A              1950       Townsville        Y
> 4:          B              1951       Villestown        X
> 5:          B              1951       Villestown        Y
> 6:          B              1951       Villestown        Y
> ```

`.I` is a special symbol which holds the row location, i.e., row index.

---

To demonstrate that this is indeed the inverse operation, `result` can be reshaped again to reproduce `wide`:

```
dcast(result, ... ~ paste0("variable", variable), length, value.var = "variable")
```

> ```
>    SUBJECT_ID SUBJECT_BIRTHYEAR SUBJECT_HOMETOWN variableX variableY
> 1:          A              1950       Townsville         2         1
> 2:          B              1951       Villestown         1         2
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
wide <- fread("variableX    variableY    SUBJECT_ID     SUBJECT_BIRTHYEAR     SUBJECT_HOMETOWN
2            1            A              1950                  Townsville
1            2            B              1951                  Villestown")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
res <- cbind(VARIABLE = rep(substr(names(df1)[1:2], 9, 9)[row(df1[1:2])], t(df1[1:2])), 
        df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), rowSums(df1[1:2])), -(1:2)])
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#   VARIABLE SUBJECT_ID SUBJECT_BIRTHYEAR SUBJECT_HOMETOWN
#1        X          A              1950       Townsville
#2        X          A              1950       Townsville
#3        Y          A              1950       Townsville
#4        X          B              1951       Villestown
#5        Y          B              1951       Villestown
#6        Y          B              1951       Villestown
```